# It was my interview question write MC/DC for (A&&B)||A

Tags: mc-dc

How many test cases will be for this boolean expression?

If I follow MCDC rules I am getting only two test cases

```
 (A&&B)||A    decision 
1 T. F.  T.      T 
2 F. T.  F.      F
```

at least one true true combination for AND gate I don't know how make without breaking other rules.

Comment: This can be simplified as just A since B input has no effect on output. Bad logic here. So just test A for true and false. B is don't care.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to create a minimum of 10 test cases. Firstly, there are two conditions; A & B, for which you need two cases each. Means a total of 4 here. Secondly, you need to create two test cases for each combination of conditions, which means an additional 4 test cases. And lastly, you would need to create two test cases for the overall decision made by the expression which will be again for a total of 2 test cases. that means it will be a total of 10 Test Cases.